# CodeAcademy - Python - Student Becomes Teacher 8/9 - Part of the Whole

Tags: python

I assume that many of you are familiar with the CodeAcademy Python class. As the title says i am at the point where i have to get the average score of the class. Here it is what i did :

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    for student in students:
        results.append(get_average(student))
        return average(results)
```

the error i get is "Oops, try again. get_class_average([alice, lloyd]) returned 91.15 instead of 85.85 as expected". And i can't seem to find my mistake for 5 hours now, so please take a look and tell me what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Fix your indentation - is that `return` in the for loop, or outside of it? It should be outside

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The indentation of your `return` statement is wrong. Currently, it is returning after the first iteration of the loop. Here is the proper indentation:

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    for student in students:
        results.append(get_average(student))
    return average(results)
```

You can also simplify your code using list comprehension:

```
def get_class_average(students):
    return average(get_average(student) for student in students)
```